# How to always run new instance of a process in C#?

Tags: c#, process

Based on this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s(v=vs.110).aspx
`Process.Start()` is not useful.

> Start may return a non-null Process with its HasExited property
>   already set to true. In this case, the started process may have
>   activated an existing instance of itself and then exited.

In my case, I want to launch a default editor for a xml in new instance so that i can use Process.HasExited property to take action on my WPF app. All i see is native samples or way complicated than thought. What is the best solution ?

```
Process process = Process.Start(MyFileXMlPath);
//Wait for the Editor to be closed.
if (process != null) 
    while (!process.HasExited) ;
```

This is what i have now. So that i uses the user's preferred editor.

Comment: Could you explain what is happening right now ? Is it working or not ? Are you just worried about the warning or you sometimes get a process with its `HasExited` property to `true`?

Comment: It always opens XML in one of the running process's window. Also process handle is null and my app wont wait for the user to finish and close the window to take action on that new xml file. So if i make Process.Start(MyFileXMLPath) to always start a new instance all problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

What's going on is expected behavior- the editor is being asked to open a file, and it is opening that file in an existing running process. One solution might be to use [Process.GetProcesses](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f3ys1f9(v=vs.110).aspx) to get all of the running processes on the box and iterate over them to find the new one, but that's likely problematic, because there is really no good way to tell which one opened the file.

What you probably want to do is to set UseShellExecute to false, run the editor you want explicitly (e.g. @"c:\Windows\notepad.exe") and pass the file name as a parameter, which is usually the convention to open a file. Obviously you'd want to pick an editor that doesn't invoke an existing instance.

Comment: Seems my requirement is very strict ( at least so far) to use user's preffered editors. So i'm going to using Interops and Native API to find the default editor and launch that program separately using ProcessInfo. Will update this thread with solution. Seems that's the only way... ?

Comment: That probably won't help. The editor itself is what is deciding to use an existing process- not the shell.

Comment: Closing: I fixed it by reading AssocProgram for file extension and launching that program with my file path. This always launches new instance.